# Is Red Imaginary?

Tags: analysis, the-shawshank-redemption

I have seen some claims that Ellis Boyd "Red" Redding (played by Morgan Freeman) from *The Shawshank Redemption* was actually just a figment of Andy's imagination. Is there any evidence to this claim in the movie? Or is there any more evidence in the source novella? I can't find any reputable citations to that effect after looking deeper.

Comment: doesn't he physically interact with multiple other people in the prison?

Comment: Is *anybody* real?

Comment: `"I have seen claims"` <-- Where have you seen these claims?

Comment: `"I can't find any reputable citations to that effect after looking deeper."` <-- Where have you looked?

Comment: He's a figment of Stephen King's imagination. So is Andy. 8-)}

Comment: And Andy also imagined Red's [parole hearings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtwXlIwozog)? And got all those items that Red supplied him from thin air? Honestly, like Mooz says, if we start asking this about characters like Red who are obviously around and part of the plot, we might as well ask if any supporting character in the history of cinema was real.

Comment: No he's real. He's also real in the book.

Comment: I can't see how it makes sense to question whether the *narrator* of a work of fiction is "real" or not in the context of that fiction. Much more likely that Dufresne is a figment of Red's imagination, not the other way around. Within the fictional world, doesn't any narrator have to ipso facto exist? Like, he narrates, therefore he is?

Comment: Curiously, it is discussed here but no good evidence is provided.   http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/is-this-a-plot-hole-in-shawshank-redemption.452820945/    Just an internet rumor I think.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, Red was very real (within the context of the story), as acknowledged by the warden and both prison guards in this scene where they take him down to Andy's cell to question him over the disappearance.